# How to know 720p or 1080p on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Usually, I used `Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor` to checking my device's resolution, but now the value is the same for `720p` and `1080p`.

So then what differentiates them ? Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that gives the correct scale factor, even for 1080p devices:

```
public int ScaleFactor
{
    get
    {
        object physicalScreenResolutionObject;

        if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("PhysicalScreenResolution", out physicalScreenResolutionObject))
        {
            var physicalScreenResolution = (Size)physicalScreenResolutionObject;

            return (int)(physicalScreenResolution.Width / 4.8);
        }

        return Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor;
    }
}
```

Here are the corresponding resolutions for each scale factor values:

- 100 => WVGA (480*800)
- 150 => 720p (720*1280)
- 160 => WXGA (768*1280)
- 225 => 1080p (1080*1980)

Source: [Handle 1080p in Windows Phone like a Pro!](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/11/06/handle-1080p-in-windows-phone-like-a-pro/)

Answer (score 1):

follow the guidance as detailed in this post
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/22/taking-advantage-of-large-screen-windows-phones.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is something from the [Nokia Developer blog](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_detect_the_screen_resolution_on_Windows_Phone).

```
public static Size DisplayResolution  
     {  
       get  
       {  
         if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major<8)  
           return new Size(480,800);  
         int scaleFactor=(int) GetProperty(System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content, "ScaleFactor");  
         switch (scaleFactor)  
         {  
           case 100:  
             return new Size(480, 800);  
           case 150:  
             return new Size(720, 1280);  
           case 160:  
             return new Size(768, 1280);  
         }  
         return new Size(480, 800);  
       }  
     }  
     private static object GetProperty(object instance, string name)  
     {  
       var getMethod= instance.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetGetMethod();  
       return getMethod.Invoke(instance, null);  
     }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

XamlEssentials is a neat set of helpers for building XAML-based applications. Recently, it added some helper utilities to make it easy to deal with large-resolution screens.

The static property `DisplayHelper.CurrentResolution` returns an enum letting you know if the resolution is `DisplayResolutions.WVGA, DisplayResolutions.WXGA, DisplayResolutions.HD720p,` or `DisplayResolutions.HD1080p`.

The static property `DisplayHelper.IsPhablet` helps to determine if the screen size is greater than 5", which lets you render differently even if you're on a 6" 720p screen, like the Lumia 1320.

The static method `ResourceHelper.AddPhabletStyle()` lets you add a specific ResourceDictionary only if the screen is greater than 5 inches, so you can easily change the layout of a page depending on the size of the screen.

XamlEssentials also has other helpers that make dealing with the new additions to GDR3 easier. You can read more about those helpers [here](http://advancedrei.com/blogs/development/xamlessentials-3-3-phablets-exceptions-and-stats-oh-my).

You can easily add XamlEssentials to your project from NuGet, or you can download the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/advancedrei/XamlEssentials).

HTH!